# Unexpected token 'done' error in for loop shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I get this unexpected 'done' token error

```
echo -e "Enter the file stem name"
read filestem
for i in {1..22}
do
    `java -cp /export/home/alun/jpsgcs/ CMorgansToTheta $filestem_$i.INPUT.par $filestem_$i.THETA.par`
done
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `#!/bin/bash` header to the top of the script?

Comment: Why do you have `java -cp ..` in backticks? Doesn't make sense, unless you're getting output of the java command to some variable.

Comment: or removing the backticks?  Does that java program really return executable `bash` statements?

Comment: I just tried it on my system, and didn't get that error. Is that the entire script? If not, please update your question to show us *all* of it (copy-and-paste, don't re-type). As @depesz says, the backticks don't make sense, but they shouldn't cause the symptom you're seeing,.

Comment: the -cp is the class path and without those i get classdefnotfound error in java. And that is all the code is and i added #! /bin/bash too. I get the same error.

Comment: If that's your exact code, please say so (in which case we have a mystery, because I don't get an "unexpected token 'done'" error with the same code). If it's not, then please *edit the question* to show us your actual copy-and-pasted code, along with the copy-and-pasted error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java command line:

```
java -cp /export/home/alun/jpsgcs/ CMorgansToTheta $filestem_$i.INPUT.par $filestem_$i.THETA.par
```

You are using:

```
$filestem_$i
```

Which will be equivalent to:

```
${filestem_}${i}
```

because underscore `_` is not considered a word boundary in shell and whole `filestem_` will be considered variable name. Most likely you should be using:

```
${filestem}_${i}
```

Can you show me output of this script?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo -e "Enter the file stem name"
read filestem
for i in {1..3}
do
    echo "java -cp /export/home/alun/jpsgcs/ CMorgansToTheta ${filestem}_${i}.INPUT.par ${filestem}_${i}.THETA.par"
done
```

Comment: Ok can you post your latest suggested script in your question.

Comment: echo -e "Enter the file stem name"
read filestem
for i in {1..22}
do
 java -cp /export/home/alun/jpsgcs/ cMorgansToTheta ${filestem}_${i}.INPUT.par ${filestem}_${i}.THETA.par
done

Comment: ok looks like you accepted other answer, probably got your problem solved.

Comment: That was a misclick. Am sorry about that.

Comment: I still get that undefined token done error. There is another weird thing that my "for" is not highlighted in the vi editor. @anubhava

Comment: I edited my answer to ask a question to you. Pls check `Can you show me output of this script?`

Comment: ./testbash.csh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: If yes then try replacing `echo "java..."` with `echo $i`

Comment: ya still getting. Lemme try ur prev comment

Comment: When i replaced echo java with $i it worked. i printed 1 to 22. But doesnt work with java inside

Comment: @Vignesh: If accepting the other answer was a misclick, you can correct it by clicking the check mark again.

Comment: What is the value of filestem you are providing?

Answer (score 5):

If the Java program writes nothing to output, your `for` loop is equivalent (because of the backquotes) to

```
for i in {1..22}
do
done
```

which produces the error you see. It's likely you simply want to remove the backquotes to run the program 22 time:

```
echo -e "Enter the file stem name"
read filestem
for i in {1..22}
do
    java -cp /export/home/alun/jpsgcs/ CMorgansToTheta "${filestem}_$i.INPUT.par" "${filestem}_$i.THETA.par"
done
```

Comment: From the shell script or from the Java program? I fixed a small bug in the shell script that would pass the wrong filenames to the Java program.

Comment: the unexpected end of file error is from the script. not java program